# Alternative representation of second derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I know that if a function $f$ is $\mathcal{C^2}(U)$ where $U$ is some neighborhood of a point $x$, by applying L'Hospitals rule twice, we can show that

$$f''(x)=\displaystyle {\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(x+2h)-2f(x+h)+f(x)}{h^2}}.$$

My question now is, if we just know that $f$ is twice differentiable at the point $x_0$, that is, there exits a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that $f'$ exists in $U$ and $f'$ is differentiable at $x$, how can we show (just by the limit definition) that the later formula holds?

I know that by definition we have

$$f''(x)=\displaystyle {\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f'(x+h)-f'(x)}{h}}=\displaystyle {\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\displaystyle {\lim_{k \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(x+h+k)-f(x+h)}{k}}-\displaystyle {\lim_{l \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(x+l)-f(x)}{l}}}{h}}$$

and if we let $k=l=h$ then we get the desired formula but I don't formally see why we can make this substitution.

Could someone give a rigurous demostration of that fact, please?

Comment: **HINT**: Use the second-degree Taylor polynomial of $f$ centered at $x_0$. By the way, you have typos in your original statement.

Comment: Oh, thank you. It was really easy to prove it by using Taylor polynomials.

Comment: Well done! :)  :)